# Python: how to download .csv files using Selenium?

Tags: python, csv, selenium

I am using `Selenium` for navigating the following website:

```
https://apps1.eere.energy.gov/sled/#/
```

I would like to have data for a city like `Boston`: what I am doing is the following:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://apps1.eere.energy.gov/sled/#/")
search = driver.find_element_by_class_name('sr-only')
search.send_keys("Boston")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(5)
tmp = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.csv-link")
```

This methodology allow me to arrive at the following webpage:

https://apps1.eere.energy.gov/sled/#/results/elecandgas?city=Boston&abv=MA&section=electricity&currentState=Massachusetts&lat=42.3600825&lng=-71.05888010000001

Now I would like to download a `csv` file under `State and National Retail Electricity Rate Trends` by clicking on `Download Chart` and then `Download Chart\Data CSV`.

I try to click on it:

```
tmp.click()
```

but I got the error:

```
ElementNotInteractableException: Message:
```

I report in the inspecting the button (`Download Chart/Data`) I would like to click by showing the screenshot of the inspection element in Firefox.

[image]

Comment: try finding the element by a different method. `XPath` is usually pretty reliable.

Comment: `a.csv-link` is not a class-name. (It includes a class-name.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two steps involved to download the file after reaching the page you specified. First you have to click on the dorp-down button then you have to select the csv data option. Using the corresponding xpath for these elements,

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="historical-electric-download"]/a[@class="no-underline"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="historical-electric-download"]/div/a[@class="csv-link"]').click()
```

Comment: Do you know how I can automatically save the file?

Comment: For that I suggest getting the direct link to the file then checkout the following question [How do I download a file over HTTP using Python?
](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python)

Answer (score 0):

`'a.csv-link'` is not class. You can try using id which is present in page.

You can try this:

`content = driver.find_element_by_id('csv-link')`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to click on Download chat first and then you are trying to click on Download Chart/Data CSV to download the CSV file , and the problem is with the locator you are using

You are trying to click on the element based on class name , but the locator doesn't have class attribute.

So try with the below xpath after clicking on download chat.

```
//a[@id='csv-link']
```

Answer (score 0):

`a.csv-link` is a css locator, so you need `driver.find_element_by_css_selector`

Comment: The OP is already using `driver.find_element_by_css_selector` by the look of their code, aren't they?

Comment: @VinceBowdren, that was a later edit. Earlier he's using `find_element_by_class_name`. You can see lots of other answers/comments are referring to that point as well